# How to release heap memory after opening a PDF file using iTextPDF and Qoppa?

Tags: android, itext, pdf-generation, heap-memory

In my app, I have to open an editable PDF file after populating a few values. For populating values, I use `PdfReader`, `PdfStamper` & `AcroFields` classes from `iTextPDF` Library. After populating values, I'm making all these objects null.

The PDF file is displayed in an activity which uses `Qoppa Library` classes like PDFDocument, QPDFNotesView. The heap size used by my app is consistent till I open a PDF. Heap size reaches very high after opening a PDF for the first time. From second time onwards, heap size increases gradually, but slightly. After opening a PDF 3 or 4 times continuously, app crashes due to `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

If I opened a PDF only once, the heap size remains the same at that high point till I run app for the next time. I have nullified all the objects of above mentioned classes when I finish that activity.

Problem is this:

> Heap size never gets down once I use these objects even if I nullify
>   after usage.

I use `itextpdf-5.1.3.jar` and `qoppapdf.jar` as private libraries. 
Can anyone help me to solve this? Thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Do you 'close' the `PdfReader` object?

Comment: Not exactly... I was just making it NULL. Now, I checked after closing it, but, no impact...

Comment: Did you use a profiler to find out whether the problem is caused by iText or Qoppa? Note that I remember some memory problem being fixed in iText related to fonts in versions more recent than 5.1.3.

Comment: I checked... the problem is caused by Qoppa...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling releaseDocument() method of QPDFNotesView class, there is a fair progress in memory freeing.

We had an object

```
    QPDFNotesView viewer = new QPDFNotesView(this);
```

called this method after usage in finally

```
    viewer.releaseDocument();
```

This has resolved my problem to an extend.